# "From" not expected on AS400 Update using a join

Tags: db2, sql-update

I am trying to update a column to today's date only if it matches data from a result set of a sub query.

I have it worked up in sql, but I am trying to convert to DB2 (**Operating system: i5/OS Version: V5R4M0**)

```
UPDATE TST.INV                                             
SET  DLI = ?                                             
FROM (SELECT Inv.PART, Inv.DLI                                                   
FROM TST.INV Inv left join TST.LOCS L ON Inv.PART = L.LPART                                          
WHERE L.LPART IS NULL AND (IC != 'C') AND (I.PRICE < 1000)                                        
) i    
WHERE  PARTNO = i.PARTN
```

This works fine using sql server, but AS400 gives me a, "From" not expected error.

Comment: Is the `?` a parameter marker?  You intend to pass in the updated value?

Comment: @Charles Yes, that is correct. I forgot to mention this is C# with oledb library.

Comment: Rather than just a fly by down vote, a reason why would be nice. I am still learning on here, hence my 699 points (which used to be 700).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 for i does not support updating from a sub-select. You can see on the [manual page for the `UPDATE` statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/db2/rbafzmstupdt.htm) that you can only specify a table or view name.

I *think* you could re-write it to do something like this, but obviously I have nothing to test with. :)

```sql
UPDATE TST.INV I
   SET DLI = ?
WHERE I.PRICE < 1000
  AND IC <> 'C'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TST.LOCS L 
    WHERE I.PART = L.LPART
  )
```

Comment: Yep, that worked out well. Thank you! We are converting old technology to .net and I still get hung up on DB/2 differences sometimes. Meanwhile we are still using the original database so everything stays in sync until the switch. Thanks for the help!